# How to record video in Apprtc using socket io?

Tags: video, socket.io, video-recording, apprtc

I am using this code https://github.com/ISBX/apprtc-node-server for video chat in my website. That is working fine but I also want to record this video. How I can achieve this?

Comment: Hi @Nilesh, did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Hi Nilesh, I also need this option in my project. Also, I have a question, is it possible to connect multiple clients with same source(using https://github.com/ISBX/apprtc-node-server project).?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.